# I have 3 Arrays, how do I add info to arrays where values match?

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have 3 arrays lets say,

array 1 has  id = 1 color = blue

array 2 has  id = 2 color = red

array 3 has  id = 3 color = red

---

I have another table with the prices for each color. From the other table i get

array 1 color = blue  price = 2.00

array 2 color = red   price = 3.00

---

how can I get

array 1 has  id = 1, color = blue,  price = 2.00

array 2 has  id = 2, color = red, price = 3.00

array 3 has  id = 3, color = red, price = 3.00

Comment: If you're doing this in a database ... you're doing it wrong. Every one of those things should be in a column in your tables, not in an array.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I wanted to understand the concept of merging arrays when I use a fetchAll function from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create below given array structure

```
   $arrFirst[0]['id'] = 1;
    $arrFirst[0]['color'] = 'blue';

    $arrFirst[1]['id'] = 2;
    $arrFirst[1]['color'] = 'red';

    $arrFirst[2]['id'] = 3;
    $arrFirst[2]['color'] = 'red';

============================

    $arrSecond[0]['color'] = 'blue';
    $arrSecond[0]['price'] = 2.00;

    $arrSecond[1]['color'] = 'red';
    $arrSecond[1]['price'] = 3.00;

    $arrSecond[2]['color'] = 'red';
    $arrSecond[2]['price'] = 3.00;

$arrFinal = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($arrFirst); $i++){

    $arrFinal = array_merge($arrFirst, $arrSecond));

}
```

---

These are ur 3 array:

```
$array1['id'] = 1;
$array1['color'] = 'blue';

$array2['id'] = 2;
$array2['color'] = 'red';

$array3['id'] = 3;
$array3['color'] = 'red';
```

From another table with the prices for each color

```
$array11['color'] = 'blue';
$array11['price'] = 2.00;

$array22['color'] = 'red';
$array22['price'] = 3.00;
```

So do this

```
$array1 = array_merge($array1, $array11));
$array2 = array_merge($array2, $array22));
$array3 = array_merge($array3, $array22));
```

Comment: But what happens when I have 50 arrays and they're dynamically generated? I used 3 as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Brian Roach's comment above. It seems like a hard example to solve because it seems it should be approached differently. For example:

```
I have 3 arrays lets say,
  array 1 has id = 1 color = blue
  array 2 has id = 2 color = red
  array 3 has id = 3 color = red
```

Having 3 Arrays, all with only one value seems very inefficient as apposed to having one Array that holds the values you listed:

```
$arrayOne = array('blue', 'red', 'red');
```

or

```
$arrayOne = array(1 => 'blue', 2 => 'red', 3 => 'red');
```

The first example above, the colors would have the id as to where they appear in the string 0,1,2,etc.